# Why does scipy.optimize.curve_fit() perform better with a defined number of aruments in fitting function?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a polynomial function of arbitrary length to some particle data, and I have noticed that curve_fit() performs much better when the arguments of the fitting function are stated explicitly rather than an undefined number of arguments being supplied, i.e

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize


def fit(x, a, b):
    return a + b*x

my_fit = optimize.curve_fit(fit, x_data, y_data)
```

performs much better than

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np


def fit(x, *args):
    return np.sum([arg * x**i for i, arg in enumerate(args)])

my_fit = optimize.curve_fit(fit, x_data, y_data, p0=[1, 1])
```

Here is a comparison between the fits when my own data is used:

[Fitting with *args and explicit coefficients comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c82GE.png)

Does anyone have any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: the search space is smaller if you give a starting point close to the expected starting point

Comment: I appreciate this is true, but I have supplied the same starting values to both optimizations here, namely [1, 1]. My question isn't so much how to get it to perform better, but rather why does it not perform the same as when the coefficients of the fit are explicitly stated.

Comment: Sorry reread it, your first example has a much simpler expression to evaluate than your second example is my guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works actually the same, the problem is that the second definition of fit does not work for numpy arrays, since `np.sum` will always result in a single number. Just specify the axis and it will work:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def fit(x, a, b):
    return a + b*x

def fit2(x, *args):
    return np.sum([arg * x**i for i, arg in enumerate(args)], axis=0)


x_data = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 200)
y_data = x_data * 1000 + np.random.normal(size=x_data.shape[0], scale=20)

my_fit = optimize.curve_fit(fit, x_data, y_data, p0=[1, 1])
my_fit2 = optimize.curve_fit(fit2, x_data, y_data, p0=[1, 1])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5))
ax1.scatter(x_data, y_data, alpha=0.5, color='red')
ax1.plot(x_data, fit(x_data, my_fit[0][0], my_fit[0][1]), color='k')
ax2.scatter(x_data, y_data, alpha=0.5, color='red')
ax2.plot(x_data, fit2(x_data, my_fit2[0][0], my_fit2[0][1]), color='k')
```

[image]

Comment: Great thank you for this solution, it works! I'm not sure if I follow why it is an issue for np.sum() to only return a single number - is this not what curve_fit() requires from the fitting function supplied?

Comment: Nope, `curve_fit` requires the fitting function to preserve the shape of `x_data`. This way it can compare the result with `y_data`  (internally I suppose it computes something like `np.sum((fit(x_data, p...)-y_data)**2)` to get the residue)